# c# .net 3.5 System.Net.Mail

Tags: c#, .net, smtpclient

I'm out of ideas!
If I do this:

```
string strTo = "email1@domain.com";
string strFrom = "email1@domain.com";
string strSubject = "turn on html";


MailMessage mail = new MailMessage(strFrom, strTo, strSubject, "<u>ok!</u>");

SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("127.0.0.1");

smtp.Send(mail);
```

it works, but I see the html tags in outlook.

if I do:

```
mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
```

before

```
smtp.Send(mail);
```

I dont receive the email!

I have checked Exchange Message Tracking, the message is not there.

I have checked the smtp Logs, I dont see my message!

I have checked the spam filter, no message!

I have checked junk email folder, not there!

wierd thing is if I change the strTo to an external email it works!!!!

going crazy here :-(

Comment: is exchange on your machine or are you trying to route through the local IIS SMTP instance?

Comment: What happens if you output to a directory instead of using a mail server. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164241.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After hours of searching, I found out if Content Filtering is Enabled with a Quarantine Mailbox, blocked messages are not logged and not found by Exchange's Message Tracking system.

This is on Exchange 2007.

All the messages were there, what a waste of time :-(

Comment: Good for you for figuring it out. Never mind the time, you learned something new.

Comment: I bet it's not a waste.  You probably learned a lot about emailing, exchange and the SMTP facet of C#.  Next time you won't have to go through all this.